# ng-model failing to bind to scope in wizard application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having an issue where ng-model is failing to bind to scope.

This section of my web app is set up like a wizard with three steps.

I want to include validation on the first step to prevent the user from reaching the second step if certain requirements are not met. However, in order to this, I need to use ng-model to bind firstName and secondName to the scope.

Here is my code so far, I've also included a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VHYM2dFScRhQ3GHWUadV?p=preview):

**wizard.html**

```
<div id="wizard-container" ng-controller="WizardCtrl as vm">

  <div id="wizard-step-container">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
    <li ng-repeat="step in vm.steps" ng-class="{'active':step.step == vm.currentStep}"><a ng-click="vm.gotoStep(step.step)" href="">{{step.step}}. {{step.name}}</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="wizard-content-container">
    <div ng-include src="vm.getStepTemplate()"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="wizard-navigation-container">
    <div class="pull-right pull-right-padding">
      <span class="btn-group">
        <button ng-disabled="vm.currentStep <= 1" class="btn btn-default" name="previous" type="button" ng-click="vm.gotoStep(vm.currentStep - 1)"></i>Previous</button>
        <button ng-disabled="vm.currentStep >= vm.steps.length" class="btn btn-primary" name="next" type="button" ng-click="vm.gotoStep(vm.currentStep + 1)">Next</button>
      </span>
      <button ng-disabled="vm.currentStep != vm.steps.length" class="btn btn-success" name="next" type="button" ng-click="vm.save()">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**step1.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <h3 class="text-center">Step 1: Please enter your full name</h3>
  <br/>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" ng-model="formData.firstName">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" ng-model="formData.lastName">
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
  <strong>Oh snap!</strong> Please enter your full name.
</div>
```

**wizard.js**

```
angular.module('dingocvWebApp')
  .controller('WizardCtrl', function ($scope, stub) {

    // Wizard methods

    var vm = this;
    vm.currentStep = 1;
    vm.formData = {};

    vm.steps = [
      {
        step: 1,
        name: 'Name',
        template: 'views/wizard/step1.html'
      },
      {
        step: 2,
        name: 'Email',
        template: 'views/wizard/step2.html'
      },
      {
        step: 3,
        name: 'Job Category',
        template: 'views/wizard/step3.html'
      },
    ];

    vm.gotoStep = function(newStep) {
      vm.currentStep = newStep;
      console.log(vm.formData.firstName);
    };

    vm.getStepTemplate = function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < vm.steps.length; i++) {
        if (vm.currentStep === vm.steps[i].step) {
          return vm.steps[i].template;
        }
      }
    };

    // Step 1

    // Step 2

    // Step 3

    $scope.jobCategories = stub.getJobCategories();

    // Yeoman defaults

    this.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
});
```

Comment: Where does the validation occur? It seems the buttons are enabled/disabled solely by their step index.

Comment: I have not implemented the validation step yet, I was planning on putting it in the `vm.gotoStep` method, so that if a particular condition was not met, the button for the next step would be inaccessible. But in order to do this, I needed to check to see if the user has provided a valid firstname and lastname.

Comment: You may be misunderstanding how `$scope` works in relation to `as`.  You should avoid mixing `$scope` and `as` within the same controller, it only serves to cause confusion.  this is only amplified by the fact that `ng-include` is a directive which creates it's own child `$scope`.

Comment: Why don't you put  $scope.formData = {
          firstname : null ,
          lastname : null 
          
        };  instead of vm.formData

Comment: basically, this approach of using `ng-include` and then trying to gather data from within it isn't going to work the way you would like.

Comment: @Claies thanks for clearing that up, what are the other options that I have available to me?

Comment: @UchihaItachi I've tried that but still undefined. This is my code here: http://pastebin.com/zjVTJMcj

Comment: Ideally, you might want to use a 3rd party tool like `ui-router` which is a state machine (can be used as a replacement for ng-route, hence it's name).  A state machine is ideal for what you are trying to do here, since each "step" is an individual state.  I am trying to find a way to expose the `$scope` from the `ng-include` to the parent controller, but I don't think it will work because of the way your function is returning the template, it may need to be compiled first;  if I figure out another way to do this I'll post an update.

Comment: another option, of course, would be to have a service to track the data across all steps, and then have each step have a controller to manage it's own access to the service, but by that point, you are just recreating a portion of a state machine....

Comment: @Claies many thanks for your feedback. Have you seen the response below from Humberto. It doesn't seem to be working as expected but I was interested to know what you think of the approach: http://plnkr.co/edit/CA2kH7?p=info.

Comment: I think I finally see what you are missing here.  because you defined `input type="email"`, angular has attached the `email` directive, and is performing validation **before** model binding.  I just didn't spot it when I was reviewing the code earlier.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D

Comment: @Claies fantastic - this got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. These were the tweaks:

**script.js**
I declared the `formData` object so that its interface is readily visible for us humans:

```
//Model
vm.currentStep = 1;
vm.formData = {firstName: null, lastName: null};
```

Each step gained a `isReady()` function that inspects the state of the `vm` object to decide if the user can interact with that step:

```
vm.steps = [
      {
        step: 1,
        name: "First step",
        template: "step1.html",
        isReady: function() { return true; }
      },
      {
        step: 2,
        name: "Second step",
        template: "step2.html",
        isReady: function() { return vm.formData.firstName && vm.formData.lastName; }
      },   
      {
        step: 3,
        name: "Third step",
        template: "step3.html",
        isReady: function() { return true; } // Didn't really care to write this one, sorry :)
      },             
    ];
```

Then, a `vm.canGoForward()` method was introduced. It checks for the readiness (and existence) of the next step in the chain:

```
vm.canGoForward = function() {
      var res = true,
      i,
      nextStateIndex = vm.currentStep + 1;

      if (nextStateIndex > vm.steps.length) {
        return false;
      }

      for (i = 1; res && i <= nextStateIndex; i++) {
        res = (res && vm.steps[i-1].isReady());
      }

      return !!res;
    }
```

(If the above code looks a bit confusing, it might be so because of the 1-index baseness of the `currentStep` member; I'd prefer it to be 0-based...)

**step1.html**
The textboxes should indeed have the "vm." object identifier prepended to the ng-model values. This instructs the angular engine to get/set the appropriate values.

**index.html**
The forward button was changed so the `ng-disabled` directive would behave accordingly to the `vm.canGoForward()` function:

```
<button ng-disabled="!vm.canGoForward()" class="btn btn-primary" name="next" type="button" ng-click="vm.gotoStep(vm.currentStep + 1)">Next step <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></button>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. Do you have a Plunker I can test?

Comment: I've given this a try and this doesn't work. I type in values in the firstname/surname text fields and still can't get onto the next page.

Comment: @methuselah see Claies response above about the e-mail validation preventing you from seeing the values before they are considered valid.